# Java POI - inserting rows as columns

Tags: java, excel, oracle, apache-poi

I'm basically getting rows from my database and pasting them in my excel file as rows. It is kinda easy, because there isn't any data conversion. Here is my code (most important part of it):

```
XSSFSheet chart1_sheet = wb.createSheet("Chart1");

String strss_chart[] = {"dataa", "inn", "closed", "application"};

hed_row = chart1_sheet.createRow(0);
for_each_header(hed_row, strss_chart);

sql = "select dataa, inn, closed, application from Chart1";
statement =  conn.prepareStatement(sql);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();  

row = 1;
while(resultSet.next()) 
{
    Row dataRow = chart1_sheet.createRow(row);
    for_each_row_func(dataRow, resultSet, strss_chart);
    row = row + 1;
}
```

And my two functions:

```
public static void for_each_row_func(Row dataRow, ResultSet resultSet, String [] strs) throws Exception
{
    int i = 0;
    for(String str : strs)
    {
         dataRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(str));
         i += 1;
    }
}


public static void for_each_header(Row dataRow, String [] strs) throws Exception
{
    int i = 0;
    for(String str : strs)
    {
         //dataRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(str));
         dataRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str);
         i += 1;
    }
}
```

My final goal is to create chart from this data, but to do it I need data **NOT** like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Data1   Data2   Data3
Data4   Data5   Data6
```

But like this:

```
Column1 Data1 Data4
Column2 Data2 Data5
Column3 Data3 Data6
```

Is there any way to do that in Java Poi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember in POI you need to create first rows, than columns as cells.
So - in your case you need create 3 rows instances

```
Row row1 = chart1_sheet.createRow(1);
Row row2 = chart1_sheet.createRow(2);
Row row3 = chart1_sheet.createRow(3);
```

than fill headers

```
row1.createCell(1).setCellValue(str[0]);
row2.createCell(1).setCellValue(str[1]);
row3.createCell(1).setCellValue(str[2]);
```

And than n iteration fill data

```
rownum = 2;
while(resultSet.next()) 
{
    row1.createCell(rownum).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(1));
    row2.createCell(rownum).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(2));
    row3.createCell(rownum).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(3));
    rownum++;
}
```

You can put all rows into collection
P.S. Sorry don't have any Java IDE on my PC - may be some mistakes in syntax. Tried to describe algorithm